# How can i print in descending order?

Tags: python-3.x

Below is my code I have printing this in ascending order I now need to print it in descending order but don't know how?

```
list = [37,-59,4,0,15,-12,9,0]
```

Comment: Thank You! for ur comments but I want to use  a for loop any idea ?

Comment: Did you want to sort it in descending order manually? Or do you want to take the list sorted in ascending order and print it via a loop?

Comment: I need to recognize the list so that it is in decending order and then write it to a fiile

Comment: Why did you remove your code from the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the list both in ascending and descending order, you can get your list in reverse like so:

`sorted_list_oldskool[::-1]`

If you only need it in descending order, AMACB's answer is probably the most efficient.

If, for whatever reason you want to take your existing sorting logic and have it produce a list in descending order, you should change

`if unsorted_list[i] <= sorted_list_oldskool[j]:`

to

`if unsorted_list[i] >= sorted_list_oldskool[j]:`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the built-in `sorted` function?

```
>>> unsorted_list = [37,-59,4,0,15,-12,9,0]
>>> sorted(unsorted_list)
[-59, -12, 0, 0, 4, 9, 15, 37]
>>> sorted(unsorted_list,reverse=True)
[37, 15, 9, 4, 0, 0, -12, -59]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly

```
print("Old way : ",sorted(sorted_list_oldskool, reverse=True))
```

Comment: is there anyway I can do it without using reverse? Thank You1!1

Comment: Just get rid of `, reverse=True`

Comment: He means he doesn't want to use the reverse flag but still have the list be reversed.